# What happens when waves of light enter your eye?

Tags: vision

I am doing a worksheet for my science class and I can't figure this one out

Comment: read this article [Can a Human See a Single Photon? by Philip Gibbs](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/see_a_photon.html). AND "The researchers found that the emission of only 54-148 photons could elicit visual experience. However, only about half of these entered the retina, due to reflection etc etc" from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_threshold#Vision)

Comment: Not during emission nor in the case of absorption light behave like a wave. Light as well as all the electromagnetic radiation has to do with photons. They hit your eyes, see Igael's comment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

The waves are refracted by the cornea, and again by the lens. Some of them are stopped by the iris, while other will pass through the pupil. They propagate through the vitreous humor and reach the retina, where they will be focused onto the photosensitive cells. Depending on their wavelength, they may excite cones (color sensitive) or rods (black and white). The excited cells create an action potential in the optic nerve, which is combined with the signals of other photocells into a pattern that is transmitted to the visual cortex of the brain.

Sounds more like biology than physics...